# Getting the name of the active window

Tags: python, windows

I want to write a python script on Windows that saves the title of the program that the user uses at a given time like the http://www.rescuetime.com .
I don't want to use rescuetime because of privacy consideration but instead write a script that does something similar myself to capture data about how much I use my computer.

Is there some easy command that I can use to read that information?

Comment: Answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266281/obtain-active-window-using-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Obtain Active window using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266281/obtain-active-window-using-python)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[From daniweb](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread134111.html)

```
  import win32gui
  w=win32gui
  w.GetWindowText (w.GetForegroundWindow())
```

Comment: win32gui is from https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32

Comment: Is there a cross platform API? I've ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

It might already be too late, but here's what should work on most operating systems:

```
import pyautogui
window_title = pyautogui.getActiveWindowTitle()
```

(I'm not sure if it works for Ubuntu, but Mac Os, Linux and Windows are normally supported)

Comment: pyautogui seems to have quite some issues when trying to install. I'm on mac os and the pyobjc-core package failed to install no matter what I tried.

Comment: `import pygetwindow` instead. I guess the feature is not ready to merge into `pyautogui`